# XSL FO generate dynamics columns

Tags: xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I'm working on an XSL FO to generate PDF using FOP.NET. I've a requirement of generating the columns dynamically based on the XML i get from the DB. Below is the XML format i've and i need to generate the columns dynamically rather than hardcoding them in the xsl fo stylesheet. ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

My goal is to build 20 types of reports and want to do it dynamically with 1 xsl fo. Is this possbile? or do I need to have 20 xsl fo files to generate the report? Please suggest an optimal way to do this.. I dont want to use itextsharp and other paid tools. (Only XSL FO)

Below is the XML that i get from SQL Server.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<Products>
<Product id="1" name="Rendezvous with Rama by Arthur C. Clarke" price="15" quantity="3" description="An all-time science fiction classic, Rendezvous with Rama is also one of Clarke's best novels--it won the Campbell, Hugo, Jupiter, and Nebula Awards." />
<Product id="2" name="Dune Chronicles by Frank Herbert" price="60" quantity="5" description="Dune is one of the most famous science fiction novels ever written, and deservedly so. The setting is elaborate and ornate, the plot labyrinthine, the adventures exciting. Five sequels follow." />
<Product id="3" name="Schindler's List by Thomas Keneally" price="21" quantity="6" description="A mesmerizing novel based on the true story of Oskar Schindler, a German industralist who saved and succored more than 1000 Jews from the Nazis at enormous financial and emotional expense." />
<Product id="4" name="Middle Passage by Charles Johnson" price="17" quantity="4" description="In this savage parable of the African American experience, Rutherford Calhoun, a newly freed slave eking out a living in New Orleans in 1830, hops aboard a square rigger to evade the prim Boston schoolteacher who wants to marry him. But the Republic turns out to be a slave clipper bound for Africa." />
<Product id="5" name="Underworld:A Novel by Don DeLillo" price="14" quantity="3" description="Underworld opens with a breathlessly graceful prologue set during the final game of the Giants-Dodgers pennant race in 1951. Written in what DeLillo calls super-omniscience the sentences sweep from young Cotter Martin as he jumps the gate to the press box, soars over the radio waves, runs out to the diamond, slides in on a fast ball, pops into the stands where J. It's an absolutely thrilling literary moment." />
<Product id="6" name="Stones from the River by Ursula Hegi" price="16" quantity="4" description="Ursula Hegi's Stones from the River clamors for comparisons to Gunter Grass's The Tin Drum; her protagonist Trudi Montag--like the unforgettable Oskar Mazerath--is a dwarf living in Germany during the two World Wars. " />
<Product id="7" name="Empire of the Sun by J. G. Ballard" price="12" quantity="3" description="Ballard's enduring novel of war and deprivation, internment camps and death marches, and starvation and survival is an honest coming-of-age tale set in a world thrown utterly out of joint." />    
</Products>
```

The columns id, name, price, quantity, description need to be bound dynamically. Any help with an example would be greatly appreciated.

My Hardcoded XSL stylesheet

```
    <fo:table border-bottom-width="5pt" width="1500pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0,51,102)" border-collapse="collapse" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(6.77)" column-number="1"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.09)" column-number="2"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.63)" column-number="3"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.94)" column-number="4"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.79)" column-number="5"/>

            <fo:table-header>
              <fo:table-row height="20.81pt" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Transaction</fo:block>
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Date</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Cust ID</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Cust No</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Client Name</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Long ID</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-header>
            <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row display-align="before">
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    1
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="left" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    Rendezvous with Rama by Arthur C. Clarke
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="right" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border="1pt " padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    3
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="right" border-top-style="solid" border="1pt rgb(0, 0, 0)" padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    $15.00
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell text-align="left" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border="1pt " padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block>
                    An all-time science fiction classic, Rendezvous with Rama is also one of Clarke's best novels--it won the Campbell, Hugo, Jupiter, and Nebula Awards.
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
```

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: What do you mean by 'generating the columns'?  Are you formatting your source as a table?  What are the differences between the report types?  We can't tell you whether or not you can do something when we don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Generating columns is, i dont want to hardcode the column names in the table in XSL FO stylesheet, Rather i would like to bind the columns that returned from SQL Server. Types of reports means, The column names may vary from a report to report. So, I need to print the column names dynamically from the XML. I'm stuck with this for last 2 weeks.. Please let me know if you need any inputs..

Comment: Below is my fo stylesheet with fixed column names, But as i said, the column names need to be populated from the XML dynamically instead of hardcoding them.. Please refer to the xsl fo stylesheet with 5 columns and 1 row hardcoded in the above original post.. Now i need to design the table with dynamic number of columns, means for 1 report i may get 10 columns, for the other report, i may get 20 columns like that.. Can you share a sample xsl fo to achieve this..

Comment: Anyone pelase help me out fixing this please? I'm not able to generate columns dynamically.. Just a code snippet in XSL FO to loop thru the columns and rows and construct a table,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT 1.0 stylesheet for your sample is below.  If you need to produce 20 variations on this, I suggest that you come up with an XML representation of the necessary information for each report -- e.g., the order and column-width for each of your attributes -- then use XSLT on that XML to generate an XSLT stylesheet like the one below.  You can then use that XSLT to generate the FO from the XML that you get from SQL Server.  It may sound complicated, but it should be simpler than trying to maintain 20 stylesheets.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
version="1.0">
<xsl:variable name="columnFontType" select="'sans-serif'"/>
<xsl:variable name="columnFontSize" select="'12pt'"/>
<xsl:template match="Products">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="a">
                <fo:region-body margin="10mm"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="a">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:table border-bottom-width="5pt"  border-bottom-color="rgb(0,51,102)" border-collapse="collapse" background-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(6.77)" column-number="1"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.09)" column-number="2"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.63)" column-number="3"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.94)" column-number="4"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(5.79)" column-number="5"/>

                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row height="20.81pt" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Transaction</fo:block>
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Date</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Cust ID</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Cust No</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Client Name</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-left-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
                                <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal" font-family="{$columnFontType}" font-size="{$columnFontSize}">Long ID</fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Product">
    <fo:table-row display-align="before">
        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@quantity"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="format-number(@price, '$0.00')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="cell">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@description"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="cell">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" border-top-style="solid" border-left-width="1pt" border-right-width="1pt" border-top-width="1pt" border-bottom-width="1pt" padding-left="2pt" padding-right="2pt" padding-top="2pt" padding-bottom="2pt">
        <fo:block>
           <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also look into `xsl:attribute-set` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets) as a way to add a bunch of attributes at once (though possibly less useful if you're generating the XSLT anyway).

Comment: Hi Tony, This works perfectly, But how to bind my columns dynamically, In the above xslt, column names are hardcoded and rows are being appended dynamically. Please suggest..

Comment: I need to build it dynamically without hardcoded column names just like the above posted stylesheet, When i use the above it is not generating any output.. Dont know why.. Please help me out with a dynamic stylesheet to handle columns from the DB.

Comment: You could implement a lookup of the column name based on the names of the attributes on the first `Product`.  If you use a formatter that implements automatic table layout, then you potentially don't need to specify the column widths.

Comment: Can you provide an example for this? I'm stuck at xslt statements.. :(. Ok, Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to build 20 types of reports and want to do it dynamically
>   with 1 xsl fo. Is this possbile?

It's possible -  if all the reports follow some common pattern.

For example, if the rows are always children of the root element, and the cells are the attributes of rows, you could do something like this (code simplified for the purpose of demonstration):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
        <header>
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/@*">
                    <cell>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    </cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>  
        </header>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <row>
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                        <cell>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </cell>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
   <header>
      <row>
         <cell>id</cell>
         <cell>name</cell>
         <cell>price</cell>
         <cell>quantity</cell>
         <cell>description</cell>
      </row>
   </header>
   <body>
      <row>
         <cell>1</cell>
         <cell>Rendezvous with Rama by Arthur C. Clarke</cell>
         <cell>15</cell>
         <cell>3</cell>
         <cell>An all-time science fiction classic, Rendezvous with Rama is also one of Clarke's best novels--it won the Campbell, Hugo, Jupiter, and Nebula Awards.</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>2</cell>
         <cell>Dune Chronicles by Frank Herbert</cell>
         <cell>60</cell>
         <cell>5</cell>
         <cell>Dune is one of the most famous science fiction novels ever written, and deservedly so. The setting is elaborate and ornate, the plot labyrinthine, the adventures exciting. Five sequels follow.</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>3</cell>
         <cell>Schindler's List by Thomas Keneally</cell>
         <cell>21</cell>
         <cell>6</cell>
         <cell>A mesmerizing novel based on the true story of Oskar Schindler, a German industralist who saved and succored more than 1000 Jews from the Nazis at enormous financial and emotional expense.</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>4</cell>
         <cell>Middle Passage by Charles Johnson</cell>
         <cell>17</cell>
         <cell>4</cell>
         <cell>In this savage parable of the African American experience, Rutherford Calhoun, a newly freed slave eking out a living in New Orleans in 1830, hops aboard a square rigger to evade the prim Boston schoolteacher who wants to marry him. But the Republic turns out to be a slave clipper bound for Africa.</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>5</cell>
         <cell>Underworld:A Novel by Don DeLillo</cell>
         <cell>14</cell>
         <cell>3</cell>
         <cell>Underworld opens with a breathlessly graceful prologue set during the final game of the Giants-Dodgers pennant race in 1951. Written in what DeLillo calls super-omniscience the sentences sweep from young Cotter Martin as he jumps the gate to the press box, soars over the radio waves, runs out to the diamond, slides in on a fast ball, pops into the stands where J. It's an absolutely thrilling literary moment.</cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>6</cell>
         <cell>Stones from the River by Ursula Hegi</cell>
         <cell>16</cell>
         <cell>4</cell>
         <cell>Ursula Hegi's Stones from the River clamors for comparisons to Gunter Grass's The Tin Drum; her protagonist Trudi Montag--like the unforgettable Oskar Mazerath--is a dwarf living in Germany during the two World Wars. </cell>
      </row>
      <row>
         <cell>7</cell>
         <cell>Empire of the Sun by J. G. Ballard</cell>
         <cell>12</cell>
         <cell>3</cell>
         <cell>Ballard's enduring novel of war and deprivation, internment camps and death marches, and starvation and survival is an honest coming-of-age tale set in a world thrown utterly out of joint.</cell>
      </row>
   </body>
</table>
```

Comment: The relative order of attribute nodes is implementation-dependent (see second-last paragraph in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model) so you will get the order that you expect except when you don't.  In practice, you might find that you always get the same order from the same SQL query every time, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @TonyGraham Well, you *could* sort them - but I believe the chances of rows **in the same document** having a different order of the same attributes are practically zero.

Comment: Yes.  I'd be more worried about an edit to the SQL query changing the order of the attributes in the XML, but swapping parsers or XSLT processors could also change things.  I have known parsers that present attributes in reverse order to the original XML, but usually I try to not have to care.

Comment: Actually I have seen the opposite and have been bitten by this before. Use a key on the first item to retrieve the values with matching attribute names in the other.

Comment: The above xslt generated pdf, but of size 1 kb and it is saying corrupted. Can you post the full structure? Based on your input, i need not have 20 different stylesheets as long as my DB returned xml format == the xml format you provided? Am i right? Please clarify

Comment: Btw, I'm using the code from this link to generate the pdf.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595650/Creating-PDF-documents-from-XML?msg=5263310#xx5263310xx  May be i need to tweak the XSLT? Please help me resolve this issue.. I've been workign on this for past 2 weeks.. :(

Comment: Hi, When i try using the above XSLT with the XML you provided, I do not see any table cells and rows in the compiled transformed XSL, i.e (.fo file). Pasting the output here for your reference:                                       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:table>
    <fo:table-header>
      <fo:table-row />
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row />
      <fo:table-row />
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</fo:root>

Comment: @PavanPuligandla As I said, the answer is simplified in order to demonstrate the principle. If you want to produce XSL-FO, you will have to make the necessary adjustments. These are pretty trivial, and I am not going to spend time on them.

Comment: Ok, No worries.. Thanks for guiding and putting me in a right direction.. Let me try this out by understanding the XSLT.. Thanks alot

Comment: I'm able to achieve it dynamically, But need to take care of styling to look like professional reports.. Thank you all for your inputs..